# EF7 and breeze.js - batch and save order

Tags: breeze, entity-framework-core

I am embarking on a new project requiring online/offline mobile sync. I am going to give Breeze a go.

There seems to be some issues with EF6 oDATA on web 2 API ([according to the breeze site](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/odata-server) with relation to batch transaction and save order.

From what I can gather, these are addressed, at least to some extent in the EF7 betas. Can anyone advise;

1. Does Breeze work out of the box with EF7
2. If not, can it be made to play nice, and how (link OK)
3. Does EF7 actually address the issues with batch transactions and save order in WebAPI2
4. Is there actually a workable solution to the issue with the edm for oData4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We definitely will support EF7 but are unlikely to release anything before EF7 gets out of beta.  As for EF6 OData, we plan on releasing an update on this within the next month.

Comment: Any updates on this please? I couldn't find anything related to EF7/Core on the Breeze release notes.